# NZ Visa application: emedical

Tags: visas, usa, new-zealand, working-visas

I need to apply for a work Visa in New Zealand, sponsored by an accredited employer (research position at a university). I currently live in the US and I am required to provide certain medical examinations to Immigration New Zealand. In the [medical certificate](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/apply-for-a-visa/tools-and-information/forms-guides-and-checklists/@@resource_summary/9b22fac1df0f45a1a7c32a80b037e736) states:

> In countries where Immigration New Zealand has an approved list of
>   panel physicians this certificate must be completed by a listed panel
>   physician. Please see our website at
>   www.immigration.govt.nz/healthinfo to find your nearest panel
>   physician. If you live in a country which does not have any panel
>   physicians, a registered medical practitioner, preferably your own
>   general practitioner, can complete this certificate.

My concern is that the only panel physician within 700miles asks me 550$. Meanwhile, my general practitioner  would charge me only 80$.

Questions:

1. Will my application be rejected if I submit the documents completed
   by my general practitioner? or
2. In case Immigration New Zealand does not accept my general
   practitioner's certificates, will they ask me to update the
   certificates rather then rejecting me?
3. Is there an *authority* that I can consult on the matter?

Comment: The form you quote has a contact phone number for questions. Admittedly, it's a New Zealand number, but a few dollars on a call to them might save you nearly $500 on medical fees.

Comment: Note that questions about long term immigration, including work permits, belong on [expatriates.se]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ***i) will my application be rejected if I submit the documents completed by my general practitioner?***

The wording of the application form includes the word ***"must"*** which indicates that in your case, applying from the USA, where there are 22 panel physicians in the continental USA, that yes you must use one of these physicians to carry out your medical.

> ***ii) in case Immigration New Zealand does not accept my general practitioner's certificates, will they ask me to update the certificates rather then rejecting me?***

This is a good question - in the case where we got my wifes employment contract wrong, NZ Immigration didn't throw out her application but instead contacted us, explained what was wrong and what it needed amending to, and allowed us to amend the application with the updated documents.

So you might get the same thing - however, I cannot find any public guidance on this, so other than experience it will be hard to answer...

> ***iii) is there an authority that I can consult on the matter?***

Yes, you can talk to [New Zealand Immigration](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/contact) and ask them directly - I have had reason to contact them several times in the past 2 years and they have been extremely helpful and supplied direct, useful answers to my questions.